# How to build interface for such enum

Tags: java, interface, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Status implements StringEnum{ 

    ONLINE("on"),OFFLINE("off");

    private String status = null;

    private Status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public static Status find(String value) {
        for(Status status : Status.values()) {
            if(status.toString().equals(value)) {
                return status;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value: " + value );

    }
}
```

Is it possible to build StringEnum interface to make sure every enum has find(), toString() and a constructor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to specify either constructors or static methods in an interface. For a good, concise explanation, check out this article: [No static methods in interfaces](http://zoom.z3950.org/bind/java/comment/static.html)

Answer (score 4):

Enums already have a [valueOf()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) (your find method) method. And "toString()" is a java.lang.Object method, so, every class will have that, in other words, you can't force it! I can't see the value of enforcing a constructor since different enums could have different initializations.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3):

1. static methods cannot be defined in interfaces
2. constructors cannot be defined in interfaces
3. `toString` is defined in `java.lang.Object`, requiring it in an interface will never result in a compile error if the method isn't defined.

Why do you want to enforce the constructor anyway? You cannot create new instances of `enum`s at runtime anyway (unless maybe via some reflection mechanism).